# What kind of project for migrated asmx service

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core, asmx

I want to migrate an old asmx webservice to .net core. It has only one method:

```
byte[] FillWithAdditionalInfo(byte[] subject)
```

This service get an object and has to fill it with some data.
I cannot change the way the clients call the webservice.

How would you build the service with .net core?

A controller with only method? How should it look like? 
And what kind of .net core template should I use it?
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your best option would be to create a *functionally identical* service that lives side by side with the existing one and then give the client a transition period.

Comment: Hi @igor, thank you for the links. I've already seen them. What I didn't find is how the entry class should look like? Should it be a controller with the same method as in my old Webservice? How should it look?

Comment: I don't think you understand what I was saying. You want a create a new functionally identical module, not a technical identical module. In asp.net core that would mean creating a web api controller with a POST method that does the same thing your web service does now but based on the new architecture.